# Get-Counter on Remote Server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to use the Get-Counter function to get performance counters on a remote Windows Server 2012:

```
Get-Counter -ComputerName "serverName" -Counter '\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\Batch Requests/sec'
```

I am getting the error:

> Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is offline.

I know the server is online and I have the appropriate permissions, because sending this code as a scriptblock and using Invoke-Command works just fine. I have a feeling this is the same issue when I try to connect to 2016 remote computer via Computer Management and it takes minutes to connect.  This happens for all 2012/2016 servers I've tried, but not 2008 R2.

What could be causing the inability to communicate?

Comment: Has PowerShell remoting been enabled on the remote computer? https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion `Get-Counter` is going to want to use remote registry access under the covers, or WMI, or some combination of these two. If you value your sanity, using PowerShell remoting to retrieve this stuff really *is* the most reliable way of doing it, in terms of not having to open ports and services you probably don't want to open.

Comment: Can you `ping` "serverName"? Try `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "serverName" -ScriptBlock { Get-Location }` and report the results.

Comment: The PowerShell way would be `Test-Connection -ComputerName "serverName"`.

Comment: I believe PowerShell remoting has been enabled - I get data when I run this: `Test-WsMan -ComputerName "serverName"`

Comment: And yes, I can run other commands against the remote server.  Including Test-Connection.

Comment: From the documentation: Get-Counter doesn't rely on PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter even if your computer isn't configured to run remote commands.